How can I use Kafka Consumers Inside a stateful api endpoint in ExpressJS?
My KafkaConfig.js
const { Kafka, Partitioners} = require('kafkajs');

class KafkaConfig {
  constructor() {
    this.kafka = new Kafka({
      clientId: "BOOKING_SERVICE",
      brokers: ['127.0.0.1:39092', '127.0.0.1:29092'],
    });
    this.producer = this.kafka.producer({ createPartitioner: Partitioners.LegacyPartitioner});
    this.consumer = this.kafka.consumer({ groupId: "test-group" });
  }

  

  async produce(messages, topic) {
    try {
      await this.producer.connect();
      await this.producer.send({
        topic: topic,
        messages: [{ value: messages }],
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      await this.producer.disconnect();
    }
  }
  

  async consume(callback) {
    try {
      await this.consumer.connect();
      await this.consumer.subscribe({ topics: ['driver_history', 'Booking_Modal', 'Drivers_stats', 'DRIVER_GPS_DATA'], fromBeginning: true });
      await this.consumer.run({
        eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
          const value = JSON.parse(message.value);
          callback(value);
        },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  
}


module.exports = { KafkaConfig };


I am attempting to utilize it in this manner, but it is attempting to connect, subscribe, and run a new consumer with every new request to /bookingSSE, which results in errors.
router.get("/bookingSSE", (req, res) => {
    if (!bookingId) {
      res.status(400).send("Error: bookingId parameter is missing.");
      return;
    }
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    res.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");

    res.write(`data: Connected!!\n\n`);

    kafkaConfig.consume((value) => {
      console.log(value);
      if (value.documentKey && value.documentKey._id === bookingId) {
        console.log('YES THE CHANGE IS BELONGS TO THIS USER');
        res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(value)}\n\n`);
      }
    });

    req.on("close", () => {
      console.log("Client connection closed.");
    });
  });

I want to run only one Kafka consumer to listen to all messages. Regardless of the number of clients connected to my SSE endpoint, I want to ensure that only one Kafka consumer is utilized. Every user should use this single Kafka consumer.

You'd need a unique consumer group for every connection to be able to read all messages. Otherwise, even if multiple connections were made, they'd then be sharing events. Therefore, it's not possible to use one consumer instance across the whole server

I am actually using MongoDB change streams to produce data changes into Kafka. Therefore, all messages are produced by MongoDB change streams pipelines. Consequently, we can receive all messages in a single consumer group as well. So, let's suppose I have millions of connections; does this mean millions of Kafka consumer groups can be created? Does Kafka support millions of consumer groups simultaneously?

The source of the data doesn't really matter. The consumer group is defined at the KafkaConfig constructor, so all connections would rebalance the same group of topics, meaning they would not all be able to read the same messages. I've not heard of any limit on consumer groups

So, basically, you're saying I should remove the consumer group from the constructor, put it in the consume function, and create a unique consumer group for each connection coming from the /bookingSSE route? Will this work fine?

I dont think its a good idea. You will not have control over the amount of data that will be read by consumer and HTTP request might get timed out.
